# Change YourKit Remote Profiler Temp Directory

Tags: java, tomcat, cloud-foundry, ubuntu-10.10, yourkit

Is it possible to change the directory that the YourKit remote profiler puts its jars in?

We're experiencing this error message when attempting to start Tomcat on CloudFoundry (running Ubuntu 10.10) with the YourKit profiling agent:

`Cannot start: failed to create jar file: /tmp/yjp201304241558.jar;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass `tmpdir=<dir>` as one the agent options.

The only problem is we can't set this in CloudFoundry, as it's trimming JAVA_OPTS on the equals... Ho-hum pip and dandy.